# Удаление дублей в многомерном массиве со сложением

Tags: php

```
array(663) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Букет"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "850"
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "850"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Букет"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "950"
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "950"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Семена"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Семена"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Семена"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "120"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "60"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "Роза (срез)"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "160"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "80"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(38) "Георгина (местн.прод)"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "200"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "40"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(36) "Петуния (местн.прод)"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "320"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "40"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(56) "Петуния  ампельная (местн.прод)"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "280"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "70"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(51) "земельная смесь (местн.прод)"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(2) "60"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(56) "Петуния  ампельная (местн.прод)"
    ["kol"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["sum"]=>
    string(3) "140"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "70"
  }
```

...
Есть такой многомерный массив, в нем есть дубли по name и price 
Необходимо искать дубли по name и price , если нашлось то складывать значения kol И sum и удалять дубль.
Подскажите как реализовать

Comment: можно добавить "кэширующий" массивчик, перебирать свой многомерный массив и дальше проверять, что если он !in_array($value_foreach, $cacheArray) то добавлять значение в $cacheArray, в общем идея такая) и дальше по логике, если нужно ещё какие-то действия сделать

Comment: я так понимаю надо индекс передавать в $cacheArray для добавления значения? а как его отловить в первоначально массиве?

Comment: зачем индекс? вам нужно перебрать массив в новый массив, в котором уже не будет дублей по name и price у вас будет 2 foreach и проверка на !in_array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пожалуй, самым простым способом будет создать аккумулирующий ассоциативный массив с ключом вида `name+price`, и итерируясь по исходному, добавлять новый элемент, если ключ отсутствует, либо суммировать значения `kol` и `sum`, если ключ уже существует.

Функция [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php) вернёт массив значений аккумулирующего массива, тем самым приведя результирующий массив из ассоциативного к обычному с целочисленными индексами.

```php
function removeDuplicates($arr) {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $key = $value["name"].$value["price"];

        if (!isset($result[$key])) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $result[$key]["kol"] += $value["kol"];
            $result[$key]["sum"] += $value["sum"];
        }
    }

    return array_values($result);
}
```

Прошу заметить, что описанная выше функция, приведёт поля `kol` и `summ` тех элементов результирующего массива, которые были "сложены", к одному из численных типов (в зависимости от наличия дробной части).
Если это поведение окажется критичным, необходимо изменить эту форму суммирования:

```php
$result[$key]["kol"] += $value["kol"];
$result[$key]["sum"] += $value["sum"];
```

на подобную:

```php
$result[$key]["kol"] = (string)($result[$key]["kol"] + $value["kol"]);
$result[$key]["sum"] = (string)($result[$key]["sum"] + $value["sum"]);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ , щас попробую

Comment: Спасибо решение работает как надо))